# jQuery как плучить все значения элементов select в одном контейнере?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется блок элементов с группой select-ов:

```
<div id="options-container">
    <div class="input-box">
        <select name="option[0][option_id]" class="select-options">
            <option value="39367:Erwachsener" selected>Erwachsener</option>
            <option value="39368:Ermäßigt">Ermäßigt</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <select name="option[0][qty]" class="qty">
            <option value="1" selected>1</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <select name="option[1][option_id]" class="select-options">
            <option value="39369:Erwachsener">Erwachsener</option>
            <option value="39370:Ermäßigt1" selected>Ermäßigt</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <select name="option[1][qty]" class="qty">
            <option value="1" selected>1</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

С помощью jQuery необходимо собрать все выбранные элементы в массив такого вида:

```
{option:[Object { option_id="39368:Ermäßigt",  qty=1}, Object { option_id="39370:Ermäßigt1",  qty=1}]}
```

думаю должно быть что-то вроде:

```
var options_info = [];
$('#options-container select').each(function (index, object) {
    var data = [];
    . . . 
    options_info.push(data);

 })
```

Подскажите как правильно собрать.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var result = $('#options-container .input-box:even').map(function(i, el) {
  return {
    option_id: $('select', el).val(),
    qty: $(el).next().find('select').val()
  };
}).get();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="options-container">
  <div class="input-box">
    <select name="option[0][option_id]" class="select-options">
      <option value="39367:Erwachsener" selected>Erwachsener</option>
      <option value="39368:Ermäßigt">Ermäßigt</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="input-box">
    <select name="option[0][qty]" class="qty">
      <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="input-box">
    <select name="option[1][option_id]" class="select-options">
      <option value="39369:Erwachsener">Erwachsener</option>
      <option value="39370:Ermäßigt1" selected>Ermäßigt</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="input-box">
    <select name="option[1][qty]" class="qty">
      <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
var result = {}
result.option = [];
$('.select-options').each(function (index, object) {
    var option = object.value;
    var qty = $(object).parent().next().find('.qty').val();
    var obj = {option_id: option, qty: qty  }
    result.option.push(obj);
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Результат будет

```
{"option":[{"option_id":"39367:Erwachsener","qty":"1"},{"option_id":"39370:Erma?igt1","qty":"1"}]}
```